# Clerk matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a `Clerk` Model with the following field:

```
status = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, choices=STATUS, default=STATUS[0][0])
```

And in `login_view` I want to check my user status. So I do:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        user_status = Clerk.objects.get(user__username=user.username)
        print(user_status)
```

Here I get this error:

```
Clerk matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: It means there is no `Clerk` with that `user`.

Comment: Great, Thank you